# Rewrite Rule with mod rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, regex

I have recently migrated a asp.net website to php. I want to redirect the old URLs to the new URLs. I need help in redirecting the following:

ex1: 
**/journals.aspx?href=issue&jid=1&id=16** to **/jor/issue/16** (if href=issue then jid 1 is always jor in the new website and id *parameter* 16 is the issue)

ex2: 
**/journals.aspx?id=118&jid=1&href=abstract** to **/jor/Article/118** (if href=abstract then it will redirect to article with article id that equals id).

Again, jid=1 is always jor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules should do it

```
RewriteEngine on

# Match issue
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} href=issue 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jid=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule journals.aspx /jor/issue/%2? [R]

# Match abstract
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} href=abstract 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jid=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule journals.aspx /jor/Article/%2? [R]
```